# Does NLog have an equivalent concept to log4net's ILoggerRepository?

Tags: logging, log4net, nlog

I'm migrating from log4net to nlog in the hopes of resolving a difficult-to-reproduce deadlock.

In our application, we use multiple named log4net Repositories from LogManager.CreateRepository. That keeps the logging in our base libraries from polluting the logs in our application libraries. Of course, there are other ways to achieve this separation, but this method worked well for us.

It seems like NLog does not have this same concept of a Repository. Is there an NLog analogue to the log4net Repository that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that there is a direct NLog equivalent to the log4net repository, and it's called a *LogFactory*. Usage is more or less identical.

Class documentation [can be found here](http://nlog-project.org/doc/2.0/netfx20/html/T_NLog_LogFactory.htm).

Instructions on how to use it are [on this page](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/How_to_configure_logging_in_a_component?).